# Latex doesn't see the tex files anymore

Tags: compilation-error

Since this afternoon, after the command

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

latex says

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `test.tex'.
<*> test.tex

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

texput.log contains:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex 2018.6.6)  6 JUN 2018 16:04
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex

End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3 strings out of 492983
 132 string characters out of 6138606
 54248 words of memory out of 5000000
 3671 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

I tried:

- [this](http://verahill.blogspot.com/2012/04/solved-latex-bug-tcfmgr-config-file.html) solution;
- several input files at different directories;
- full uninstall/reinstall of texlive.

Nothing works...

I'am using Antergos (a derivative of Arch).

Comment: Can you find texput.log? Is it in the folder of test.tex?

Comment: what does `echo $TEXINPUTS` say ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
`echo $TEXINPUTS` says `/home/patrick/LaTeX/mesmacros`. I need this directory for a personal package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I completed my post.

Comment: @PatrickAugeau Can you test with `/home/patrick/LaTeX/mesmacros/:`?

Comment: @samcarter after `export TEXINPUTS=~/LaTeX/mesmacros:`, I get the  same messages. I just tried with an empty TEXINPUTS too. Same output message...

Comment: @PatrickAugeau as I suspected:-) You have told tex _only_ to look there and not in the current directory,, it should work with the trailing :. though, or `.:/home/patrick/LaTeX/mesmacros/:` to be really sure that `.` is at the front.

Comment: So, now `echo $TEXINPUTS` gives `.:/home/patrick/LaTeX/mesmacros:`. But I still get the same output :/